# Uncaught ReferenceError: translate is not defined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
const styles = theme => ({
    imageContent: {
        transform: `${translate('-50%','-50%')}`
    }
});
```

I want to apply CSS property translate for the div inside a component. So how to refer CSS properties from React Component?
Uncaught ReferenceError: translate is not defined.

Comment: from `translate` is coming.. ? Are you meanig the css property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening because you have included `translate` in your literal's placeholders. However, there's no need for the placeholder. You should change this to:

```
transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
```

You can learn more about template literals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thanks @Michael Flores.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have div:

```
<div style={{background: white}}> 
   Something
</div>
```

Also you can initiate a const before:

```
const styleForaDiv = {background: "white"}
<div style={styleForaDiv}> </div>
```

Notice that all styles should be camelCased, so background-image turns into backgroundImage and you just use comma inside style dictionary:

```
const styleForaDiv = {backgroundImage: "url('')", backgroundSize: "cover" }
```